# glossary in long-booktabs style has no bottomrule in minipage

Tags: glossaries, minipage, rules, booktabs

I want to put a `longbooktabs` glossary in a minipage environment, but when I do that it curiously loses the `bottomrule`. Is there anything I can do about that?

As Nicola Talbot commented it suffices to put a `longtable` in a minipage environment to recreate the issue, see the shorter MWE below.

[image: sample mwe output]

#### Original MWE

Don’t forget to run `makeglossaries`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ex}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\begin{document}
A \gls{ex} glossary with \texttt{style=long-booktabs} has a \texttt{bottomrule}:

\printglossary[style=long-booktabs]

But if put in a minipage, the \texttt{bottomrule} vanishes:

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\printglossary[style=long-booktabs]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

#### Shorter MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{longtable}{l}
    \toprule
    Col\\
    \midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot
    A\\
  \end{longtable}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `longtable` environment is designed for spanning multiple pages, but the contents of a `minipage` can't be broken and that's causing interference. Since a `minipage` can't span multiple pages, it's best to use `tabular` rather than `longtable` inside it. (I'm assuming you only have a short glossary that can fit on a single page.)

You could define your own style that works like `longtable` but uses `tabular` instead:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}

\newglossarystyle{tabular}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{tabular}{lp{\glsdescwidth}}}%
     {\bottomrule\end{tabular}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \toprule \bfseries \entryname & \bfseries
  \descriptionname\tabularnewline\midrule}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
     &
     \glssubentryitem{##2}%
     \glstarget{##2}{\strut}\glossentrydesc{##2}\glspostdescription\space
     ##3\tabularnewline
  }%
  \ifglsnogroupskip
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \else
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\glspenaltygroupskip}%
  \fi
}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ex}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\begin{document}
A \gls{ex} glossary with \texttt{style=long-booktabs} has a \texttt{bottomrule}:

\printglossary[style=long-booktabs]

In a minipage using \texttt{tabular} instead of \texttt{longtable}:

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\printglossary[style=tabular]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossaries]

An alternative approach is to use one of the supplementary `long` styles defined in `glossary-longextra`, which is provided with the `glossaries-extra` package. You can switch to using `tabular` instead of `longtable` by using:

```
\GlsLongExtraUseTabulartrue
```

before the style is set. The `long-name-desc` style is similar to the `long-booktabs` style but it doesn't include the location list. Your example includes it, but if your real document has `nonumberlist` then this might be a convenient option:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[postdot]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{glossary-longextra}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ex}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\begin{document}
A \gls{ex} glossary with \texttt{style=long-booktabs} has a \texttt{bottomrule}:

\printglossary[style=long-booktabs]

In a minipage using \texttt{tabular} instead of \texttt{longtable}:

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\GlsLongExtraUseTabulartrue % use before style is set
\printglossary[style=long-name-desc]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of sample glossaries]

The `glossary-longextra` styles are designed to fill the page width. If you don't want this you can redefine `\glslongextraSetDescWidth` to do nothing:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[postdot]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{glossary-longextra}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ex}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\begin{document}
A \gls{ex} glossary with \texttt{style=long-booktabs} has a \texttt{bottomrule}:

\printglossary[style=long-booktabs]

In a minipage using \texttt{tabular} instead of \texttt{longtable}:

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\GlsLongExtraUseTabulartrue % use before style is set
\renewcommand{\glslongextraSetDescWidth}{}% don't adjust \glsdescwidth
\printglossary[style=long-name-desc]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossaries]